# php statements fail to work when wrapped in a function

Tags: php, function, mysqli

The code below works fine when its not in wrapped in a function

```
$opt = 'logo_img';
$sql="SELECT option_value FROM r0_options WHERE option_name='".$opt."'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
var_dump($row);
```

However when I do as follows, and call the function, it gives NULL.

```
function get_result($opt){
    $sql="SELECT option_value FROM r0_options WHERE option_name='".$opt."'";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
    var_dump($row);
}

get_result('logo_img');
```

Comment: ever heard of variable scope? *well, there you go; now you have* and that's what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are not passing `$db` variable, either pass it to function or do the following:

```
function get_result($opt){
    global $db;

    $sql="SELECT option_value FROM r0_options WHERE option_name='".$opt."'";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
    var_dump($row);
}

get_result('logo_img');
```

Comment: oh god. I've spent too much time w/o coffee. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are forgotten to pass he '$db' to your function:

function get_result($db, $opt){